# Converting XML Polygons into Google Maps

Tags: javascript, xml, oracle, polygons, kmz

I have a XML (KMZ) file with polygons that refer to geographical areas, like counties and states, and I want to be able to read this data into googlemaps.

I'm thinking it can be done more conveniently for me in 2 ways:

a) Parsing the xml file into inserts into a Oracle Database
b) Reading the xml directly from my google maps page using Javascript. (Data would be placed in arrays, I presume).

Either way, does anyone have some tips on how to do this efficiently?
Maybe someone made a great part of the code needed to do this already.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the google maps API v3, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

Regards, Lea.